# How to paste same information into 2 different files?

Tags: linux, centos, bash-script

I'd like to create two files in `/etc/skel` using a script which does many other things in addition to the creation of the files in `/etc/skel`.
The part from script regarding `/etc/skel` looks like this:

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/skel/.vimrc
:set nu
set incsearch
:set ignorecase
:set smartcase
:set ts=2
EOF
```

I tried adding `&& /etc/skel/.virc` on the end of the first line in the script but to no avail. 
Is there any way to do that other than doing the whole `cat` again into the other file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tee`.

```
tee /etc/skel/{.vimrc,.virc} > /dev/null <<EOF
:set nu
set incsearch
:set ignorecase
:set smartcase
:set ts=2
EOF
```

Comment: Yet another [useless use of `cat`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html). (since corrected)

Comment: @cjm: Indeed. I have fixed the offending code.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the fact that the here document created the file `/etc/skel/.vimrc` and make a copy of it:

```
cp /etc/skel/.vi{m,}rc
```

You put that line right after the here document.